# Enable default after event.preventDefault() in function?

Tags: jquery

Condition:

1. User open in width <= 800, function is executed
2. then change to > 800, because function already executed, there some effect still running, and I cant click anchor.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function stuff(){
        //event.preventDefault() 
        new mlPushMenu(document.getElementById('menu'), document.getElementsByClassName('btnslick')[0], {
            type : 'cover'
        });
    };

    function jqUpdateSize(){ 
        var windowwidth = $(window).width();

        if (windowwidth <= 800){
           //function on
        } else {
            //try to stop/off function and return to default

        }
    };
    $(document).ready(jqUpdateSize);
    $(window).resize(jqUpdateSize);
});
```

How to stop function and return to default ?

I tried to store to new function and set with on/off but not working?

Comment: what are you trying to do? If these are style changes, add a class to `body` or whichever appropriate parent element, and you can toggle this class according to `windowwidth`.

Comment: There's no default action on the window `load` event anyway (and your `stuff` function doesn't have any in-scope `event` identifier other than the IE-specific global [which Chrome includes to throw a bone to IE-specific case, but Firefox does not]).

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function stuff(){
var windowwidth = $(window).width();
 if (windowwidth <= 800){
    new mlPushMenu( document.getElementById( 'menu' ), document.getElementsByClassName( 'btnslick' )[0], {
            type : 'cover'
        });
}
};
function jqUpdateSize(){ 
        $(window).on('load',stuff);
};
$(document).ready(jqUpdateSize);
$(window).resize(jqUpdateSize);
});
```